# Bandwidth improvements expected from switching to Wayland or Mir?

Tags: x11, benchmark, wayland

I was intrigued by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90955/26076) regarding [why X is not scalable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90951/26076).

I'm unable to find any specific speed comparisons between x forwarding on these different protocols.

How much % gain in network speeds should I expect and will these be at a compromise of significant memory/CPU resources?

I'm into low resource computing, but about to transfer to a country with worse internet than Japan and fear I may have to compromise power for speed.

Comment: IIRC Wayland behaves more like VNC over the network. you may also be interested in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIctzAQOe44 (a talk about X11 and Wayland).

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find anything convincing either with respect to X, Wayland, and Mir. I did find this case study that showed the differences between X11 SSH, FreeNX, and VNC.

- http://vis.lbl.gov/Events/SC08/RemoteX/index.html

[image: ss of results tables]

#### An alternative?

When dealing with remote access there are 2 ways to broach the problem. Most people tend to go with the remote display approach since it seems to be the most natural way to think of the problem.

But there is another way to deal with it. If the systems on the other end of line are Linux/Unix boxes then it's fairly trivial to use tools such as `ssh`, `screen`, or `tmux` to log into the distant server, and do console work without ever needing to touch a GUI in X.

Additionally there are alternative methods to accessing GUI's by making the files you need to access at the other end of the line, available to locally installed tools, as if they were part of the local filesystems. Tools such as FUSE or even the builtin capabilities of `gvim` or `vim`.

#### Example - FUSE/sshfs

If you want to remotely mount some distant directory you can simply do the following:

```
# make mountpoint
$ mkdir ~/blah

# mount remote dir. through sshfs
$ sshfs root@somehost:/root ~/blah

# use it

....
Now you can use any tools such as gvim/vim to 
access files through this FUSE mountpoint, 
~/blah
....

# umount when done
$ fusermount -u blah
```

#### Example - gvim/vim

Here I'm sitting on my local system, `lappy`. I invoke `gvim` but reference a file on a remote system:

```
lappy$ gvim scp://joeuser@remotey//home/joeuser/.bashrc
```

I'm then presented with the file `.bashrc` from the remote computer, locally to my instance of `gvim` on my system, lappy.

Always remember the motto that the best solutions to problems are the ones that avoid them completely!

Comment: From my experience, the more often one needs to access remote files, the more often one resorts to doing it directly on the remote machine with a console application running on the same machine as the file (and usually running it in a terminal multiplexer - connection drops teach you it is a Good Thing (TM)).

Comment: I'm preferring to use a GNU screen session via GateOne with a bunch of windows so that even if my connection drops, I can pick up where I was without having to respawn windows and connections (GateOne runs on a more reliable remote server), but when in a hurry I agree, direct to the machine in question is often used